# How to rename relation function in eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I using Laravel 5.3 .this my query and I want in result array the 'children_rec' renamed to 'node'.

```
 $boxes = Boxes::with('children_rec')
                ->whereNull('box_id')
                ->with('position')
                ->get()
                ->toJson(128);
```

UPDATE:
Relation code:

```
public function child()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany('PTA_OIMS\Boxes', 'box_id');
}

public function children_rec()
{
    return $this->child()
        ->with('children_rec')
        ->with('position');
}
```

thanks

Comment: What does the return structure look like? Why can't you just manipulate the array?

Comment: @tadman: result structure:https://pastebin.com/NFfWS0s2

Comment: Edit your question to include any relevant code, please don't add it as a cluttered comment.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549526/how-to-alias-in-laravel-eager-loading

Comment: you may need to use `with` eloquent

Comment: You can use attribute accessors as described in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867569/laravel-eloquent-serialization-how-to-rename-property

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Laravel supports aliasing a relationship.

You should rename your relation to your desired name:

```
public function node()
{
    return $this->child()
        ->with('node')
        ->with('position');
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
$boxes = Boxes::with('node')
               ->whereNull('box_id')
               ->with('position')
               ->get()
               ->toJson(128);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using attribute accessors to hide the relationship and then show the accessor in the results, for example:

```
public function getNodeAttribute() {
  return $this->children_rec;
}
protected $hidden = array('children_rec');
protected $appends = array('node');
```