# Eloquent column alias in lumen5.8

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, lumen

How to give alias in replated table hasMany relationship.

**Controller**

```
$templates = UserMaster::where ( 'INACTIVE', '=', 0 )->with('contact')->get ();
```

**Model**

```
public function contact(){
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Contact::class,'CONTACT_ID');
}
```

I can try this code my but give error

```
$templates = UserMaster::where ( 'INACTIVE', '=', 0 )->with('contact as CONTACT')->get ();
```

So how give alias in with query?

Thank you

Comment: The 'with' function is not translated 1:1 to SQL. Thus an alias on relations is not possible without further ado. 

If you want to do this, define a method to rename the retrieved data.

Comment: So you mean directly not possible?

Comment: I can't imagine. Then you would have to work directly with the DB::class

Comment: Maybe you look here, there was an additional function to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549526/how-to-alias-in-laravel-eager-loading